# How to access Hash Map inside string using backreference

Tags: ruby, hashmap, gsub

I am using gsub method, and using //1 to get a back reference.

In that, say,

> map = { "Stack" => "overflow"}
>
> "Stackoverflow".gsub(/(Stack)overflow/,"Non\\1")

will print `"NonStack"`. I am getting this correctly.

But **I want to use map** here, like

```
"Stackoverflow".gsub("/(Stack)overflow/","#{$map['\\1']}")
```

so that it will print `overflowoverflow`. But i tried various combinations and I am not getting this.

Comment: Are you using `//1` or `\\1`? Which?

Comment: @sawa I am using `\\1`

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT Also, your example actually uses a String instead of a Regexp, so it would match a literal '(Stack)', not capture 'Stack' :)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thanks I corrected!

Comment: I will try to explain you why your code didn't work tomorrow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a block, then the global variables `$1` .. `$9` hold matches. This achieves what you want:

```
map = { 'stack' => 'overflow' }
p "stackoverflow".gsub(/(stack)(overflow)/) { map[$1] + $2 }
# => overflowoverflow
```

Alternatively, you can just pass a variable to the block:

```
map = { 'stack' => 'overflow' }
p "stackoverflow".gsub(/stack/) { |match| map[match] }
# => overflowoverflow
```

See [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) for reference.

Comment: `"Stackoverflow".gsub(/(Stack)overflow/){ puts map[$1] }` this prints an "" string

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT It prints `"overflow"` here. Are you sure your `map = { 'Stack' => 'overflow' }` ?. Just copy-paste my code and run it :) Notice my `map` has 'stack' in lowercase.

Comment: Knippers k. its my mistake `S` and `s` case sensitiveness in map is the problem.